# Get std::list in other file

Tags: c++

I would like to know how I can access a std::list on an other file?

My list in a.h

```
class MobActivity
{
public:
MobActivity(){};
~MobActivity(){};
typedef struct _CreatureData
{            
     WORD           MapID;
     bool           IsDead;
     DWORD          KilledTime;
     bool           isSpawned;
     RwUInt32       DisplayID;

} CreatureData;

typedef std::list<CreatureData*> MONSTERLIST;
typedef MONSTERLIST::iterator MONSTERLISTIT;
MONSTERLIST                 m_monsterList;

};
```

Now Id like to access this list on an other file named b.h

```
void MobActivity::RunSpawnCheck(CNtlPacket * pPacket, sVECTOR3 curPos)
    {
        CGameServer * app = (CGameServer*) NtlSfxGetApp();

        CreatureData * creaturelist;
        for (MONSTERLISTIT it = m_monsterList.begin(); it != m_monsterList.end(); ++it )
        {
            creaturelist = (*it);


                CNtlPacket packet(sizeof(sGU_OBJECT_CREATE));
                sGU_OBJECT_CREATE * res = (sGU_OBJECT_CREATE *)packet.GetPacketData();
                res->wOpCode = GU_OBJECT_CREATE;
                res->sObjectInfo.objType = OBJTYPE_MOB;

        }
    }
```

Any idea how I could do it?

I can do the for loop like this

```
for (auto it = app->mob->m_monsterList.begin(); it != app->mob->m_monsterList.end(); ++it )
```

but more I dont know.. it keep saying creaturelist is undefined and this `m_monsterList == (*it);` also says its undefined

**Got it working!**

Comment: In the definition of class `MobActivity` you should *declare* the member function, `void RunSpawnCheck(CNtlPacket * pPacket, sVECTOR3 curPos)`. The `b.h` file should *probably* instead be an implementation file `b.cpp`. Anyway, at the top of that file `#include` the `a.h` file. Also, if you have not already, place a `#pragma once` at top of the `a.h` file. Note that all uppercase is perceived as shouting by many, and also makes name clashes with macros more probable.

Comment: It would be easier to find an answer, when you provide complet and compileabe code examples, including your includes. And try to throw out as much code as possible.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you explained your answer to so people travelling this way in the future can see how you solved it.